# How overcome with '#' , coming in URL through DeepLinking in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to implement navigation in Ionic  2. I have tried with DeepLinking and i got the result, but '#' sign is comming in URL.
When '#' sign will come in URL then Google Analytic will not recognize the website, that's why i have tried to implement navigation in different ways like Angular 2 Routing, that supports both (HTML5 or hash URL style), but unable to implement in Ionic 2.

Ex-  http://localhost:8100/#/registration - This one working fine but i want without '#'.
Like http://localhost:8100/registration

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I put in a PR for @ionic/app-scripts 3.2.5 to remedy this:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/pull/1545

In the meantime you can edit some project and dependency files to enable it:

src/app/app.module.ts:

```
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,
        {
            locationStrategy: 'path'
        },
        {
            links: [
                { component: RegistrationPage, name: 'registration', segment: 'registration' },
                { component: LoginPage, name: 'login', segment: 'login' },
                { component: HomePage, name: 'home', segment: '' }
            ]
        })
```

src/index.html:

```
<head>
    ...
    <base href="/" />
    ...
</head>
```

node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/dev-server/http-server.js:

```
function createHttpServer(config) {
    var app = express();
    app.set('serveConfig', config);
    app.get('/', serveIndex);
    app.use('/', express.static(config.wwwDir));
    app.use("/" + serve_config_1.LOGGER_DIR, express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'bin'), { maxAge: 31536000 }));
    // Lab routes
    app.use(serve_config_1.IONIC_LAB_URL + '/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'lab', 'static')));
    app.get(serve_config_1.IONIC_LAB_URL, lab_1.LabAppView);
    app.get(serve_config_1.IONIC_LAB_URL + '/api/v1/cordova', lab_1.ApiCordovaProject);
    app.get(serve_config_1.IONIC_LAB_URL + '/api/v1/app-config', lab_1.ApiPackageJson);
    app.get('/cordova.js', servePlatformResource, serveMockCordovaJS);
    app.get('/cordova_plugins.js', servePlatformResource);
    app.get('/plugins/*', servePlatformResource);
    if (config.useProxy) {
        setupProxies(app);
    }
    app.all('/*', serveIndex);
    return app;
}
```

The line `app.all('/*', serveIndex);` is what will redirect any 404 file or directory not found errors to index.html. The locationStrategy: 'path' setting can then work normally with deeplinks and redirects under these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pathLocationStrategy instead of HashLocationStrategy.

Add this in app.module.ts

```
import { LocationStrategy,
         PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

...

@NgModule({
...
providers: [
{
   provide: LocationStrategy,
   useClass: PathLocationStrategy
},
...
```

Or other way is

```
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
        locationStrategy: 'path'
    })
```

And make sure to have a valid base href.

Comment: I have tried in both, but not working, give Runtime Error- 

 @NgModule({ 
  imports: [ IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {locationStrategy: 'path'}, { 
  links: [ 
   { component: RegistrationComponent, name: 'Registration', segment: 'registration' }
  ]
  })],
  providers: [...] 
 })

 @NgModule({ 
  imports: [ IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, { 
  links: [ { component: RegistrationComponent, name: 'Registration', segment: 'registration' }, ] 
  }) ], 
  providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }, ...] 
 })

Comment: Hi, I need to pass a parameter as well, like `http://localhost:8100/feedback/767`, how can i do this?

Comment: @MarcAlexander : yes this wont work when you refresh the page, this is general behaviour for any SPA with clean URLS.  because when you refresh the page : server tries to find the page mapped to the URL . example if you hit abc.com/pqr , then server tries to find pqr/index.html which doesnt exist. 

to solve this , you have to write configurations on your server : to point every request at index.html

Answer (score 0):

So here is the list of things which I did. Hope this helps.

1. We need to remove # in path of every url because Google Analytics rejects the urls with # in them. In App Module , add {locationStrategy: 'path'} to your App Module as follows :

   ```
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
     locationStrategy: 'path'
   })
   ```

2 .Now # is removed from the url. But when you refresh or directly access the url, this wont work because this is expected behaviour for any SPA. When you refresh the page , server tried to find the page at the location mentioned. As stated by @Parth Ghiya above For eg: if you hit localhost/abc , then server tries to find abc/index.html which actually doesn't exist.So to resolve this , you have wrote configurations on my server i.e to point every request to index.html . I am using node express server to deploy the app. Use the following code to route every request to index.html -

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path')
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "www")));

app.use('/*', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname+ '/www' + '/index.html');
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("listening to Port", app.get("port"));
});
```

Comment: What about navParams? I get undefined instead of the value from the URL